# How to delete session data when page refresh in Laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made mail send program with Laravel5, that works so well.

```
public function sendMail(Request $request){
    $data = session() -> all();

    // send mail to User and Admin
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtouser'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to($data['email']) -> subject("To User");
    });
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtoadmin'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to('admin@example.com') -> subject("To Admin");
    });

    return view('test.complete');
}
```

But if an user do page reflesh, mail send everytime.
So I need to delete session data when page refresh.
I wish to do this.

```
public function sendMail(Request $request){
    $data = session() -> all();

    // send mail to User and Admin
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtouser'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to($data['email']) -> subject("To User");
    });
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtoadmin'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to('admin@example.com') -> subject("To Admin");
    });

    if( page reload... ){
        $request -> session() -> flush();
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else { // page reload not yet...
        return view('test.complete');
    }
}
```

Any solves?

P.S.
Thanks everyone for your reply.
Yeah I can delete session data after mail sent.
But if I try to reload after session data deleted,
I will catch TokenMismatchException.
So I think that need redirect when session data is empty like this.

```
public function sendMail(Request $request){
    $data = session() -> all();

    // send mail to User and Admin
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtouser'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to($data['email']) -> subject("To User");
    });
    Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtoadmin'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message -> to('admin@example.com') -> subject("To Admin");
    });

    $request -> session() -> flush();

    if(empty( $request -> session() ...? ){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else {
        return view('test.complete');
    }
}
```

How can I catch empty session data?

Comment: Do a redirect instead of returning a view. See [post/redirect/get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: I think you don't need to check for page reload. As you already sent the mail can't you just delete the session after sending mail?

Comment: try to use `session->flush()` after each email is sent. if you need to use the email details inside your view then save them to **other** variable and then flush the session immediately and use the new variable in your view and do not use the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone.
Sorry it is too late to answer this question like a turtle.
Finally, I solved with this.

```
 public function sendMail(Request $request){
     $data = session() -> all();

     // send mail to User and Admin
     Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtouser'], $data, function($message) use($data){
         $message -> to($data['email']) -> subject("To User");
     });
     Mail::send(['text' => 'test.mailtoadmin'], $data, function($message) use($data){
         $message -> to('admin@example.com') -> subject("To Admin");
     });

     $request -> session() -> flush();

     return view('test.complete');
 }
```

And, redirect to document root if token mismatch found in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) { 
             return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

I wish to catch tokenmismatchexception in Controller but I cant find a way.
That is why I use handler.php